# Complex conjugation for absolute value calculation

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I want to calculate $|e^{2\pi i/3} a + e^{4\pi i/3}b|^2$, where $a, b \in \mathbb{C}$. To do this, I multiply it by its complex conjugate, or,
$$
(e^{-2\pi i/3}a^* + e^{-4\pi i/3}b^*)(e^{2\pi i/3} a + e^{4\pi i/3}b) = |a|^2 + |b|^2 + e^{2\pi i/3}a^*b + e^{-2\pi i /3}ab^*
$$
However, I can't figure out why this is necessarily real.  If $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ then obviously it is real because $ab^* = a^*b$ and the two latter terms become a cosine.  How about in the more general case though?

Comment: Note that for any complex number $z$, $$z+z^*=2\text{Re}(z)$$

Comment: Are you sure there's not a minus sign in one of the exponents in the original exercise?

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $z = e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}}a^{∗}b$, then we have $z^{*} = e^{-\frac{2 \pi i}{3}}ab^{*}$. You can easily check that $z + z^* = 2Re(z)$. And then substitute this into your equation.